# What does ケルヒャー mean?

Tags: katakana, names

The dictionary is no help. A web search links it to a home steam cleaning product on [kaercher.com](https://www.kaercher.com/jp/), but I'm not sure how. Is it a product type, or the activity of steam cleaning, or...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ケルヒャー is a transliteration of the company name [*Kärcher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4rcher). At least in Germany, the brand name is almost synonymous with their high-pressure cleaners. (Like Sellotape or Xerox or Velcro.)

The resulting word is actually pretty close to the original word (a German surname)

> Kärcher [[kɛʁçɐ]]
>   ケルヒャー [[keɺɯçaː]]

(closer than what would be possible in English, at least).

Answer (score 1):

It is the name of a German company which produces and sells cleaning devices.

Comment: Just when you think you can work out katakana phonetically...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the name of the company rather than a word itself.